# Php Slim framework unittest mock Router

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, slim

I have created a wrapper for the Slim request in my application to have the ability to create some custom methods on the Request object.

```php
class Request extends SlimRequest
{
    /**
     * Get authorization token.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getAuthToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->getHeaderLine('FOOBAR-TOKEN');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a route parameter.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getRouteParam(string $name): ?string
    {
        return $this->getRoute()->getArgument($name);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the route instance.
     *
     * @return Route
     */
    public function getRoute(): Route
    {
        return $this->getAttribute('route');
    }
}
```

My problem comes when trying to create unit test for this class. The way I have been testing requests is by using Slims build in environment mocks. The first function I added a header to the request which can be seen below, but I can't figure out how to add a Route object to the request

```php
$request = Request::createFromEnvironment(Environment::mock());
$request = $request->withHeader('FOOBAR-TOKEN', 'superSafeExampleToken');
```

I tried creating the request with a request options but `$this->getAttribute('route');` returns `null`

```php
$requestOptions = [
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'POST',
    'REQUEST_URI' => ' / foo / bar',
    'QUERY_STRING' => http_build_query($requestParameters),
];
$environment = Environment::mock($requestOptions);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean about creating a Route object - this should be the set in your routes for your app and not in the request.

Comment: I know which happens when I create the application, and I then have access to the route object.

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#route-object

I just don't know how to set that up so I can use it in a unit test

Comment: Your route object is set once it has started processing the request, so after you do the `$app->run();`, this will call whichever route you have defined for the request.  Once you are processing this request, that is when it should be set.

Comment: The test will just not be that isolated if I have to boot the entire app to perform it. I'm going to try and create a Route class and then add it as an attribute to the request with $request =  $request->withAttribute('route', $route) and see if I can make that work

Comment: You may take a look at this Slim 3 [example](https://github.com/odan/prisma/blob/master/tests/TestCase/ApiTestCase.php#L46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the solution was the following

```
public function testGetRouteParam()
{
    $route = $route = new Route('GET', '/foo/{bar}', []);
    $route->setArguments(['bar' => 1]);
    $request = Request::createFromEnvironment(Environment::mock());
    $request = $request->withAttribute('route', $route);

    $this->assertEquals(1, $request->getRouteParam('bar'));
    $this->assertNull($request->getRouteParam('baz'));
}
```

Comment: thanks, this was helpful